# Charged Capacitor in serial RLC-Oscillator

Tags: dc, oscillator

So one of my Professors has given out a practice example I'm unable to finish. Given is the following circuit:
[image: DC RLC-Oscillator in series]

Determine the time function \$u_C(t)\$ by solving the differential equation:
$$u_C''+2\delta u_C'+\omega_0^2u_C= \omega_0^2U_0
$$

So I get the (presumably) correct solution, for the following values: $$
C=5.6\mu\mathrm{F}\text{ with: }U_{C,0}=u_C(0)=48\mathrm{V}\\
L=43.3664\mathrm{mH}\\
R=176\Omega
$$

My solution is:
$$
u_C(t)=\mathrm{e}^{-\delta t}(K_1t+K_2)+U_0
$$

With a DC-Source voltage \$U_0=19.5\mathrm{V}\$ I can determine \$K_2\$ to be the following:
$$
u_C(0)=1(K_1*0+K_2)+19.5\overset{!}{=}48\Leftrightarrow K_2=48-19.5=28.5\mathrm{V}
$$
So my Prof lists in his possible solution for \$K_1\$ to be non-zero, which to me makes no real sense, since the circuit is open for \$t<0\$ and the inductor cannot have a jumping current, meaning the current at \$t=0\$ is \$0\mathrm{A}\$. Or am I completely missing something?

**Edit :** I just remembered this question of mine, and I don't know how I got this wrong. My general solution of \$u_C(t) = \mathrm{e}^{-\delta} (tK_1+K_2) + U_0\$ is correct, I just, for some reason calculated the derivative incorrectly and got confused with \$\dot{u}_C(0)\$. Since \$\dot{u}_C=\frac{1}{C}i\$, the inital condition has to be \$0\$, since the inductor prevents jumps in the current, hence I get:
$$
u_{C,0} = K_2 + U_0 \Rightarrow K_2 = u_{C,0} - U_0 = 28.5\mathrm{V}\\
\dot{u}_{C}(t) = -\delta\mathrm{e}^{-\delta t}(tK_1+K_2) + \mathrm{e}^{-\delta t}K_1\\
\Rightarrow 0 = -\delta K_2 + K_1 \Leftrightarrow K_1 = \delta K_2
$$

Comment: Where are you accounting for \$u_L(t) = L\frac{di}{dt}\$?  Where does the \$\delta u'_C\$ come from in your equation?

Answer (score 2):

Well, when we apply [Faraday's law of induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction), we can see that:

$$\text{V}_\text{R}\left(t\right)+\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)-\text{V}_\text{source}\left(t\right)=-\text{V}_\text{L}\left(t\right)\tag1$$

Using the relations between voltage and current in the different components:

- Resistor ([Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law)):
  $$\text{V}_\text{R}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_\text{R}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{R}\tag2$$
- [Capacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor#Current%E2%80%93voltage_relation):
  $$\text{I}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\text{V}_\text{C}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{C}\tag3$$
- [Inductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductor#Constitutive_equation):
  $$\text{V}_\text{L}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_\text{L}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}\tag4$$

Where \$x'(t)\$ implies: \$x'(t)=\frac{\text{d}x(t)}{\text{d}t}\$.

Because this is a [series circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits#Series_circuits) we know that all the currents are the same, so we write:

$$\text{I}\left(t\right):=\text{I}_\text{R}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\text{I}_\text{L}\left(t\right)\tag5$$

So, we can rewrite equation \$(1)\$:

$$\text{I}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{R}+\text{I}\left(t\right)\cdot\frac{1}{\text{C}}-\text{V}_\text{source}'\left(t\right)=-\text{I}''\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}\tag6$$

Now, we can apply [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) on equation \$(3)\$:

$$\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)=\left(\text{s}\cdot\text{v}_\text{C}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{V}_\text{C}\left(0\right)\right)\cdot\text{C}\tag7$$

Solving for \$\text{v}_\text{C}\left(\text{s}\right)\$ gives:

$$\text{v}_\text{C}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)+\text{C}\cdot\text{V}_\text{C}\left(0\right)}{\text{C}\cdot\text{s}}\tag8$$

Where \$\text{i}\left(\text{s}\right)\$ is Laplace transform of the solution to equation \$(6)\$.

The second initial condition can be found using equation \$(1)\$, \$(2)\$, and \$(4)\$:

$$\text{I}\left(t\right)\cdot\text{R}+\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)-\text{V}_\text{source}\left(t\right)=-\text{I}'\left(t\right)\cdot\text{L}\tag9$$

Using your values and \$t=0\$, we get:

$$\underbrace{\text{I}\left(0\right)}_{=\space0}\cdot176+\underbrace{\text{V}_\text{C}\left(0\right)}_{=\space48}-\underbrace{\text{V}_\text{source}\left(0\right)}_{=\space\frac{39}{2}}=-\text{I}'\left(0\right)\cdot\frac{3388}{78125}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space$$
$$\text{I}'\left(0\right)=-\frac{4453125}{6776}\approx-657.191\space\text{A/s}\tag{10}$$

---

Now, using your values and using Mathematica I found:

$$\text{V}_\text{C}\left(t\right)=\frac{57}{154} e^{-\frac{156250 t}{77}} (156250 t+77)+\frac{39}{2}\tag{11}$$

With the following codes:

```
In[1]:=FullSimplify[
 DSolve[{x'[t]*176 + x[t]*(1/((56/10)*10^(-6))) - 
     D[195/10, t] == -x''[t]*(433664/10^4)*10^(-3), x[0] == 0, 
   x'[0] == -(4453125/6776)}, {x[t]}, {t}]]

Out[1]={{x[t] -> -((4453125 E^(-156250 t/77) t)/6776)}}

In[2]:=FullSimplify[
 LaplaceTransform[-((4453125 E^(-156250 t/77) t)/6776), t, s]]

Out[2]=-(31171875/(8 (156250 + 77 s)^2))

In[3]:=FullSimplify[(((-(31171875/(
       8 (156250 + 77 s)^2))) + ((56/10)*10^(-6))*48)/(((56/
         10)*10^(-6))*s))]

Out[3]=(6 (8 - 115966796875/(156250 + 77 s)^2))/s

In[4]:=FullSimplify[
 InverseLaplaceTransform[(6 (8 - 115966796875/(156250 + 77 s)^2))/s, 
  s, t]]

Out[4]=39/2 + 57/154 E^(-156250 t/77) (77 + 156250 t)
```

Comment: Sorry for the very late response. I got the identical solution, just not as simpliefied as yours. Using the Laplace-Transform is the right way for such a problem, I just had a mental blockade on the initial condition of the current in the circuit. I understand now, that the inductor itself prevents jumps in the current, hence we can say, that \$i(0)=0\$, or, for my equation : \$\dot{u}_C(0)=0\$.